# Wordpress SQL statement help needed?

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress

I want to select with sql latest post from one category,I know how to select latest post from all category but dont know how to JOIN tables.Can someone help me with this,and explain a little.
My sql statement.

```
SELECT id,post_title,post_date FROM wp_posts ORDER BY post_date ASC
```

How to select from one category,I'm trying some code,looking INNER JOIN examples,but it doesnt work,help please.

Comment: What are you trying to join?  And what do the tables look like?

Comment: Is it not easier to just use one of the built in wordpress functions to retrieve results from a category? eg

    <?php query_posts('category_name=yourcategory&order=ASC'); ?>

Comment: It is a wordpress database,I'm trying to JOIN two tables so can SELECT only posts from one category

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Going by [image: WP ERD]

I'd say you want to join through to wp_terms using appropriate join conditions and specify which term you want in your WHERE clause.

```
SELECT
  p.*
FROM wp_posts p
JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr ON p.id = wtr.object_id
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON wtr.term_taxonomy_id = wtt.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN wp_terms wt ON wtt.term_id = wtt.term_id
WHERE wtt.name = 'Some Term'
```

You may need further restrictions on the join/where.

Comment: I wish all answers be so illustrative like yours.

Comment: Wow nice graph,yes,I want to select only posts from one category where there status is publish order by date.Can you explain me on example how to do that?
I'm looking this graph,it helps but it would be much easier if you can explain me on example how to do that.Tnx in advance.

Comment: SELECT
    p.* 
FROM 
    wp_posts p 
WHERE 
    post_status='publish' 
ORDER BY 
    post_date
JOIN 
    wp_term_relationships wtr ON p.id = wtr.object_id
JOIN 
    wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON wtr.term_taxonomy_id = wtt.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN 
    wp_terms wt ON wtt.term_id = wt.term_id
WHERE 
    wtt.name = 'my-cat'

It doesnt work this for me,why?

Comment: Here is code that works : SELECT * 
FROM wp_posts p
JOIN wp_term_relationships wtr ON p.ID = wtr.object_id
JOIN wp_term_taxonomy wtt ON wtr.term_taxonomy_id = wtt.term_taxonomy_id
JOIN wp_terms wt ON wtt.term_id = wt.term_id
WHERE wt.name = 'galerija' AND p.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY p.post_date

tnx ChrisCM for graph and help